# Magento2 phrases in some specific modules are not translated

Tags: magento-2.1, i18n

I have installed [arabic lang pack](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-arabic-language-pack.html).
But phrases from Magento_Checkout module are not being translated.
these are the i18n files in my installation:

```
./app/i18n/Burooj/ar_SA/ar_SA.csv
./app/code/Burooj/Applinks/i18n/ar_SA.csv
./app/design/frontend/CzoneTech/fresh/i18n/ar_SA.csv
```

for an instance `"Go to Checkout",شراء,module,Magento_Checkout` in present in `/app/i18n/Burooj/ar_SA/ar_SA.csv` but the phrase is not translated in mini cart.

How can I debug this ?

Answer (score 1):

Magento 2 has had issues with translations in Knockout templates for some time. A solution found in the M2 Github issues is relevant. I recommend trying the solution found here:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/8508#issuecomment-305417154